Rails Test with bearer Authorisation
I am currently trying to test my rails controller. As it is an API application, I am using JWT token to authenticate/authorize users. Here is my rails test file using Minitest:
class AuthorControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include JwtHelper

  setup do
    @jwt_token = fetch_jwt_token
  end

  test 'should create author' do
    post authors_url,
         params: { author: { biography: 'MyText', date_of_birth: '2021-07-01', first_name: 'MyString',
                             last_name: 'MyString' } },
         headers: { Authorization: "Bearer #{@jwt_token}" }

    assert_response :created
  end
end

My JWT is correct and I get it (if I add "put @jwt_token", to my setup, it is print everytime before the test, and it is a correct one). However I still received a 401 Unauthorised error and not success message.
What could go wrong?
PS: here is my validation token function
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  before_action :validate_token

  private

 def validate_token
    # validate token presence
    token = request.headers['Authorization']&.split(' ')&.last
    unauthorized and return unless token

    jwk_response = HTTParty.get('https://my-jwt-server/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo',
                                headers: { 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{token}", 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
    if jwk_response.code == 200
      puts 'pass the token presence verification'
    else
      puts 'error'
      unauthorized and return
    end
  end
end

and here is my JWT helpers for my test
module JwtHelper
  def fetch_jwt_token
    response = HTTParty.post('https://my-jwt-server/protocol/openid-connect/token', body: {
                               client_id: 'frontend',
                               username: 'Librarian',
                               password: 'test',
                               grant_type: 'password'
                             }, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' })

    response.parsed_response['access_token'] # Adjust according to your JWT server's response format
  end
end


Are you certain it is the token verification that is failing and not some other authorization mechanism. i.e. Librarian doesn't have access to create an Author?

Yes the mistakes was mine, I just messed up with the authorization validating mechanism
